# Prove that image of any connected subset of $\Bbb R$ under $f$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Consider the function $f : \Bbb R \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ defined by $$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \sin \frac 1 x & \quad x \gt 0 \\
            0 & \quad x \leq 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Prove that $f(E)$ is connected for any connected subset $E$ of $\Bbb R.$

What I observed is that $f((-\epsilon, \epsilon)) = [-1,1],$ for any $\epsilon > 0.$ Does it help anyway? I know that connected subsets are precisely intervals.

So for any interval $I$ lying on the left of the origin we have $f(I) = \{0\},$ which is connected. If one of the endpoints of $I$ are on the left of the origin and the other is on the right of the origin then $f(I) = [-1,1],$ which being an interval is again a connected subset of $\Bbb R.$

Comment: Distinguish two cases: (a) The interval does not have zero in its closure and (b) zero is in the closure. For (a) you can use the fact that continuous functions map connected sets to connected sets.

Comment: Please do not undelete post after having gotten an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments are correct, but do not cover all cases. We shall use your observation in the form that $f((0,\epsilon)) = [-1,1]$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

As you know $E$ connected means that $E$ is an interval (which may be unbounded to the left and/or right). Define $E_1 = E \cap (-\infty,0]$ and $E_2 = E \cap (0,\infty)$. We have $E = E_1 \cup E_2$. Either both $E_i$ are intervals or one is an interval and the other is empty.

1. If $E_1 = \emptyset$, then $E = E_2$ and $f(E) = f(E_2)$ is connected because $f \mid_{(0,\infty)}$ is continuous.
2. If $E_2 = \emptyset$, then $E = E_1$ and $f(E) = f(E_1)  = \{0\}$ which is connected.
3. If both $E_i \ne \emptyset$, then $E_2$ contains some $(0,\epsilon)$. Thus $f(E_2) = [-1,1]$ and therefore $f(E) = f(E_1 \cup E_2) = f(E_1) \cup f(E_2) = \{0\} \cup [-1,1] = [-1,1]$ which is connected.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good starting point. It is also true that $f\bigl([0,\varepsilon)\bigr)=[-1,1]$, that $f\bigl([0,\varepsilon]\bigr)=[-1,1]$, that $f\bigl((-\varepsilon,0]\bigr)=[-1,1]$, and that $f\bigl([-\varepsilon,0]\bigr)=[-1,1]$ for every $\varepsilon>0$. Now use the fact that $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ to prove what you want to prove in the remaining types of intervals. Besides, don't forget the intervals of the type, say, $(a,b)$, with $a<0<b$. And, of course, they can also be closed or neither open nor closed.

Comment: I have also included the intervals $(a,b)$ with $a < 0 < b.$ See my edit.